# Renew command with argument into command without argument

Tags: macros

Recently I saw someone using

```
\be 
 ... 
\ee
```

instead of

```
\begin{equation} 
 ... 
\end{equation}
```

which seems like a nice compact notation to use and I would like to add it to my own template.
However, if I try to simply use

```
\renewcommand{\begin{equation}}{\be} 
\renewcommand{\end{equation}}{\ee}
```

that gives me about a dozen errors so that obviously does not work.
How does one go about doing this? I'm still a bit new to this.

Comment: Don't do it. Your editor will no longer be able to do correct syntax highlighting, and it makes your source more difficult to read for others, e.g. if you want to ask a question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer gives good reasons why to avoid.  But if you insist, here is one way: `% BEGIN EQUATION MODE
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
% BEGIN EQUATION MODE WITH LABEL
\newcommand{\beql}[1]{\begin{equation}\label{#1}}
% END EQUATION MODE
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}`

Comment: I agree with Ulrike. Learn to use your editor more optimally.

Comment: IMHO one should be least dependent on the editors. So if you want to go beyond the boundaries of the syntax highlighting provided by a specific editor, please do that. Don't stick to them. Also TeXstudio has a feature which will encompass the new and renewed environments/commands in the default highlighting.

Comment: I agree with the others it is not at all recommended to do this, and it will not work with amsmath environments like `align` but it will in fact not give errors with `equation`   If you want help from the site with an error please always provide a complete small document that makes the error and also the exact error from the log, both in code blocks. it is impossible to debug "about a dozen errors" the number of errors rarely tells anything as after the first error  the rest are usually spurious due to the way tex recovers from errors.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. I have used the default notation (\begin{equation} etc.) until now and shall continue to do so.